# Why is NaT data type not responding as NaN?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's an example of the original data:

```
28      22/03/2015
29      22/03/2015
30      22/03/2015
31             NaN
```

I then change the format as follows:

```
df.loc[2,2:]=pd.to_datetime(df.loc[2,2:]).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Which gives me this as data:

```
28     2015-03-22
29     2015-03-22
30     2015-03-22
31            NaT
```

Now when I try to replace NaT (because it gives me errors when uploading it to Postgres), I two different situations:
1. Nothing changes when I do this:

```
df.loc[2,]=df.loc[2].fillna('Unknown')
```

2. All the data changes to "Unknown" when I add "inplace=True":

```
df.loc[2,]=df.loc[2].fillna('Unknown', inplace=True)

28     None
29     None
30     None
31     None
```

Is this a problem with how I've formatted it? With all other data types fillna works on NaN.

Comment: When you call a function such as `fillna` with `inplace=True`, you're not supposed to assign the results, since with `inplace=True` it doesn't return anything (or, in other words, returns `None`) so assigning it back will clear all the data. So at least that part can be explained that way...

Comment: What are your column names? And indices? Your use of `.loc` might be the issue...

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC what's missing from my code now?

Comment: @filbranden tried it with df.['columnName'] and it does the same thing.

Comment: _what's missing from my code now?_ An example which is easy to try/reproduce.